# How to upload image in cPanel in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-1.8

**OS == CentOS7**

**Python == 3.6.5**

**Django == 1.8**

I have a "news" app in my Django project. And in the models of this app has ImageField. Trying to upload an image with .jpg format in django admin interface, it is in cPanel. But whenever uploading bar completes in 100%, it throws me to "Not Found" page, and says that *The requested URL /admin/news/post/add/ was not found on this server.*

I thought it is server side problem, but when contacted with hosting provider's support team. They said it is code side problem not theirs. There is no permission to any apache nor nginx. OS

Main **urls.py**

```
# from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

if settings.DEBUG is False:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root' : settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
    ]
```

(news)app url, **news/urls.py**

```
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$', views.NewsView.as_view(), name='posts'),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^index', views.search, name="search"),
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
    url(r'^league/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.league_detail, name='league_detail'),
]
```

(news) app **models.py** NOTE! Error is in ***Post*** class'es ImageField:

```
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_userforeignkey.models.fields import UserForeignKey
# import datetime
# from django.utils.six import with_metaclass
# from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

# excelFile = open('news/static/excelFile/table.csv', 'r').read()
# newEntry = excelToDB(someField=excelFile)
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

POSITIONS = (
    ('Darvozabon', 'Darvozabon'),
    ('Himoyachi', 'Himoyachi'),
    ('Yarim Himoyachi', 'Yarim Himoyachi'),
    ('Hujumchi', 'Hujumchi'),
)


class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    abbrv = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Club(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='clubs')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    coachName = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    abbrv = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Player(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player')
    club = ChainedForeignKey(
        Club,  # the model where you're populating your countries from
        chained_field='league',  # the field on your own model that this field links to
        chained_model_field='league',  # the field on Country that corresponds to newcontinent
        show_all=False,  # only shows the countries that correspond to the selected continent in newcontinent
    )
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    goalsLeague = models.IntegerField()
    pNumber = models.IntegerField()
    position = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=POSITIONS, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName + " " + self.club.name


class Post(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', blank=True, null=True)
    club = ChainedForeignKey(
        Club,  # the model where you're populating your countries from
        chained_field='league',  # the field on your own model that this field links to
        chained_model_field='league',  # the field on Country that corresponds to newcontinent
        show_all=False,  # only shows the countries that correspond to the selected continent in newcontinent
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    player = ChainedForeignKey(
        Player,  # the model where you're populating your countries from
        chained_field='club',  # the field on your own model that this field links to
        chained_model_field='club',  # the field on Country that corresponds to newcontinent
        show_all=False,  # only shows the countries that correspond to the selected continent in newcontinent
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    img = models.ImageField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = UserForeignKey(auto_user_add=True, verbose_name='The user that is automatically assigned', related_name='posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Post)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.img.delete(False)
```

**settings.py:**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'news/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'news/static/images'),
)
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'www.favourite.uz', 'favourite.uz']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_userforeignkey',
    'simplesearch',
    'smart_selects',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_userforeignkey.middleware.UserForeignKeyMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('Uzbek')),
    ('ru', _('Русский')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

# MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'
# MODELTRANSLATION_TRANSLATION_REGISTRY = 'news.translation'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'futbik_version_7.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'news/templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'news.context_processors.add_variable_to_context',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'futbik_version_7.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {
#     'default': 'south.db.sqlite3'
# }

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tashkent'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = False


# MODELTRANSLATION_DEBUG = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
```

I am wondering whether it is possible to develop Django like projects in cPanel. The reason of using this is the cost. I cannot afford VPS orVDS for today. So I need help if someone encountered such situation! I appreciate your help!

*P.s. I am beginner in Django!*

Comment: your problem need some debugging, for example make sure media dir exists and has valid permission, make sure file is written there, make sure media dir is a valid (use prints), add something on media dir (manually from cpanel file maanger) and check if files is served with expected link....

Comment: Hi, sorry for late respond!

Comment: @aliva I changed the directory of MEDIA_ROOT to _public_html/media_, and the page succesfully have seen the images, but still no luck in admin interface